# Can't POST JSON to server using Netty

Tags: json, post, netty, channel

I'm stuck on a really, really basic problem: Using `HttpRequest` to `POST` a wee bit of JSON to a server using Netty.

Once the channel is connected, I prepare the request like this:

```
HttpRequest request = new DefaultHttpRequest(
    HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, postPath);
request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
String json = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}";
ChannelBuffer buffer = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(json, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);
request.setContent(buffer);

channel.write(request);
System.out.println("sending on channel: " + json);
```

The last line prints out `{"foo":"bar"}`, which is well-formed JSON.

However, a really simple echo server I wrote in Python using Flask shows the request, but it has no `body` or `json` field, like the body couldn't be parsed into JSON correctly.

When I simply use `curl` to send the same data, then the echo server does find and parse the JSON correctly:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"foo":"bar"}' -X POST http://localhost:5000/post_path
```

My pipeline in Netty is formed with:

```
return Channels.pipeline(
    new HttpClientCodec(),
    new MyUpstreamHandler(...));
```

Where `MyUpstreamHandler` extends `SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler` and is what attempts to send the `HttpRequest` after the channel connects.

Again, I'm at a total loss. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you have http keep alive on or not, but if you do, you may have to send the content length in the header.

Comment: This was, indeed the problem. I had originally put the following: `request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(buffer.getByteArray().length));`
But the underlying `byte[]` of the buffer seems to come from a pool, and is not derived from the `json` that the buffer was copied from. And so, looking back it was returning `53` instead of `13`.

At this point, I omitted this call to `setHeader`, sort of hoping that Netty would simply add it for me based on the parameter passed to `request.setContent`.

As Jestan pointed out, I must use `buffer.readableBytes()`.

Answer (score 7):

As Veebs said, you have to set some http headers, I too had same the problem and lost for hours, I got it working with following code :).

```
    import static org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpHeaders.Names.*;

    ......  

    HttpRequest httpRequest = new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpMethod.POST, "/post_path");

    final ChannelBuffer content = ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(jsonMessage, CharsetUtil.UTF_8);

    httpRequest.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
    httpRequest.setHeader(ACCEPT, "application/json");

    httpRequest.setHeader(USER_AGENT, "Netty 3.2.3.Final");
    httpRequest.setHeader(HOST, "localhost:5000");

    httpRequest.setHeader(CONNECTION, "keep-alive");
    httpRequest.setHeader(CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(content.readableBytes()));

    httpRequest.setContent(content);

    channel.write(httpRequest);
```