# Sending HTTP Post Request in Netty

Tags: java, json, http, post, netty

I'm trying to wrap my mind around how I would go about constructing an HTTP Post request for a web server.

I found this code

```
HttpRequest httpReq=new DefaultHttpRequest(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,HttpMethod.POST,uri);
httpReq.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.HOST,host);
httpReq.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONNECTION,HttpHeaders.Values.KEEP_ALIVE);
httpReq.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.ACCEPT_ENCODING,HttpHeaders.Values.GZIP);
String params="a=b&c=d";
ChannelBuffer cb=ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(params,Charset.defaultCharset());
httpReq.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_LENGTH,cb.readableBytes());
httpReq.setContent(cb);
```

From what I can deduce, it appears that this request will send a POST request with two values, a and c, which are equal to b and d, respectively.

What I'd like to be able to do is submit a JSON request. For example, if my post-data needed to be

```
{
    "test": "value",
    "key": "value",
}
```

would I just replace the a=b&c=d with that string itself? Also, I *must* have the content-type set to application/json.

If anyone could help me or point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This issue is still hard :L

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898279/cant-post-json-to-server-using-netty

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek it is for Netty 3.X. setContent and ChannelBuffers no longer exists in Netty 4.0

Answer (score 0):

My example for JSON requests via Netty 4.x to `localhost/target`:

```
String JSON_DATA = "{    \"test\": \"value\",    \"key\": \"value\"}";
FullHttpRequest request = new DefaultFullHttpRequest(HTTP_1_1, POST, "/target",
        wrappedBuffer(JSON_DATA.getBytes(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)));
request.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.HOST, "127.0.0.1");
request.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaderValues.APPLICATION_JSON);
request.headers().add(HttpHeaderNames.ACCEPT_ENCODING, HttpHeaderValues.GZIP);
request.headers().set(HttpHeaderNames.CONNECTION, HttpHeaderValues.CLOSE);

outboundChannel.writeAndFlush(request);
```